# C Socket Client/Server doesn't work in real world environment

Tags: c, sockets, timeout

Basically my server/client socket functions work perfectly fine using the loopback address, or even my eth0 address on my laptop. Howver, once I move my code into the test environment it will be used in, I get connection time outs, or connection refused depending on the changes I have tried to make.

As of now the code I am about to post results in a Connection time out.

CLIENT

```
void buildConnection(int* txmt_sock, Connection conn_info)
{
    struct sockaddr_in servinfo; /* server address */

    servinfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servinfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servinfo.sin_port = htons(conn_info.port);
    if(inet_aton(conn_info.ip, &servinfo.sin_addr) < 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Read error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        abort();
    }
    /*int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)*/
    if ((*txmt_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("client: socket");
        abort();
    }

    /*int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);*/
    if (connect(*txmt_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&servinfo,(socklen_t)sizeof(servinfo))     == -1) 
    {
        close(*txmt_sock);
        perror("client: connect");
        abort();
    }
    printf("Successfully connected on port %s:%d\n", conn_info.ip, conn_info.port);
}
```

SERVER

```
void returnConnection(Connection* conn_info)
{
    int status, ext_conn, yes = 1;
    char portStr[5];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo;
    struct sockaddr_storage ext_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    struct sockaddr *restrict;

    /* Formats PORT for use with getaddrinfo(), can't cast #define*/
    snprintf(portStr, 6, "%d", conn_info->port);

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));      /*make sure the struct is empty*/
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;           /*don't care IPv4 or IPv6*/
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;       /*TCP stream sockets*/
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;           /*fill in my IP for me*/


    if ((status = getaddrinfo(NULL, portStr, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    if((conn_info->listen_sock = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    if(setsockopt(conn_info->listen_sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    } 

    if(bind(conn_info->listen_sock, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bind error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    if(listen(conn_info->listen_sock, 1) == 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Listening error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    addr_size = sizeof(ext_conn);

    if((ext_conn = accept(conn_info->listen_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&ext_addr, &addr_size)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Accept error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    };
    conn_info->receiving_sock = ext_conn;
}
```

This is a multi-threaded program that collects image data from 8 different ports/threads. I use my Connection struct to store all the pertinent data for each thread. Each thread has it's own Connection.

```
typedef struct connection{
    char* file;
    int port;
    char* ip;
    pthread_t *thread;
}Connection;
```

Connection->ip is not used in the server side, but is uses on the Client side. The server side of the code resides on a multi-cpu, multi-nic IBM server. I am not certain if I need to manually assign the IP or not because of that. I am assuming the OS and network cards manage on their own using the incoming PORT numbers from the clients, and the individual PORT numbers that my Server threads listen on. But all I know is that it works on my laptop to itself.

It's a completely new vanilla install on this machine with openSuse, so I don't think any of the ports I am using, 5050-5053 and 5055-5058, are turned off or anything like that.

Comment: You have a potential buffer overflow in the server, in your `snprintf` call: You say that the size of the destination buffer is six bytes but it's only five. So if the port number is 10000 or higher it will write past the end of the buffer. If the destination buffer is an array, always use `sizeof(...)`.

Comment: Yeh, I've looked at thing many a time, I'm just lazy.

Comment: I'd check your firewall settings, the linux firewall produces results like that if it's blocking the port you did a listen() on.

Comment: I came in this morning thinking it could be something along those lines.

Comment: Yeh I guess this can be closed as unproductive, the firewall by default on our install disk fas everything closed. So that's all it was.